# Is there anyway to set the Specification-Vendor or Implementation Vendor other than in a Manifest.MF file

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, manifest.mf

I would like to set the values for Specification-Vendor and Implementation Vendor such that they are set when my code is run without having been packaged into a jar file.

In the jar file I can add them to the manifest.mf file but when debugging in Intellij or running the mvn test phase these values are not picked up from the unpackaged META-INF directory.

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y question. Why do you need these values to be set when running/debugging code through an IDE?

Comment: Because the JAI library requires them to be set when manipulating TIFFs. I did not write that library.